# При использовании ServletContainer получаю 404 not found!

Tags: java, java-ee, rest, jersey

Прошу обратить внимание на коменты в web.xml и других примерах!

Из того что я вижу проблема с ServletContainer! Или у меня не правильные настройки ?

Буду рад если кто объяснит почему при использовании в моём случаи контейнера я получаю 404 ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
   http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
 version="3.1">
```

```
<description>JerseyTesting</description>
<servlet-name>WebService</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>web.service.JerseyDemo</servlet-class>

// When i use this construction -> upper
//i got the response as needed! 

<description>JerseyTesting</description>
<servlet-name>WebService</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>

//When i using this construction I got 404 not found, at the same url path!

 </servlet>  //Here the mapping

  <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>WebService</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/users/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  </web-app>
```

===================================================================

```
// Using it with: And this working!
//<description>JerseyTesting</description>
//<servlet-name>WebService</servlet-name>
//<servlet-class>web.service.JerseyDemo</servlet-class>

@Path("users")
public class JerseyDemo extends HttpServlet{

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

   PrintWriter writer = resp.getWriter();
   writer.print("Hello from Servlet");

   }
  }
```

======================================================================

```
  // Using it with: And this not working 404 not found error!
  //<description>JerseyTesting</description>
    //<servlet-name>WebService</servlet-name>
    //<servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>

@Path("users")
public class JerseyDemo {


@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String getResponse(){

    return "Hello From Jersey Servlet";
    }
 }
```

======================================================================

web lib folder:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
 Using it with: And this working!
<description>JerseyTesting</description>
<servlet-name>WebService</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>web.service.JerseyDemo</servlet-class>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
  <!--

  <servlet>
   <servlet-name>WebService</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
   <init-param>
   <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
   <param-value>tests</param-value>
   </init-param>
   <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

   //This method not working!! 404 Error!

  -->

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>WebService</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>tests.JerseyServiceDemo</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>

   // This method Working!
</servlet>
```

```html
 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>WebService</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/users/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

```html
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.testing.functionality</groupId>
  <artifactId>TestingProjects</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>TestingProjects Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.19</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
      <version>1.19</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
      <version>1.19</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
      <version>1.19</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>TestingProjects</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала проверьте ссылку: `locahost:8080/TestingProjects/users/users`

Попробуйте добавить конфиг в web.xml примерно так

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
                 com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
            </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
         <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
          //тут ваш package
         <param-value>web.service</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/users/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Ну и посмотрите рабочий [пример](https://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/jersey-hello-world-example/)

Comment: Попробувал с твоим примером! Получаю тоже самое! Добаволяю еше пример!

Comment: Насчёт рабочего примера я всё понимаю. но у меня выдаёт 404 если я использую подход работы с ServletContainer как в первом так и во втором случаи.

Comment: Надеюсь вы переходили /users/users? Если это проект только начался, выложите часть на гитхаб воспроизводимого кода, и опубликуйте ссылку сюда.

Comment: Я на данный момент прошол по users/users. Получил ошибку! 
HTTP Status 405 - HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL! 
Знаеш в чём дело ???

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/565679/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B1-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81-jersey