# Ошибка при передачи запроса на веб сервис Jersey

Tags: java, java-ee, веб-служба, jersey

http://localhost:8080/ProjectsTesting/users/users Запрос на данный URL выдаёт ошибку, которая снизу! Из ошибки не могу нече понять.. Null Pointer exception а дальше что, с чего Null Pointer ?

```
@Path("/users")
public class JerseyServiceDemo{

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String getResponse(){

    return "Hello From Jersey Servlet";
 }
}
```

## Или:

```
  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  public Response getResponse(){

    Response response = Response.ok().entity("Hello From Jersey Servlet").build();

    return response;
}
```

```html
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>WebService</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>tests</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>WebService</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/users/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

> > **com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.mapMappableContainerException The RuntimeException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container**
> >      java.lang.NullPointerException   **Что означает эта ошибка, что происходит** ?????
> >
> > > java.lang.NullPointerException
> > >           tests.JerseyServiceDemo.getResponse(JerseyServiceDemo.java:85)
> > >           sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> > >           sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> > >           sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> > >           java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
> > >           com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
> > >           com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:185)
> > >           com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
> > >           com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
> > >           com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
> > >           com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
> > >           com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
> > >           com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1542)
> > >           com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1473)
> > >           com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)
> > >           com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)
> > >           com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)
> > >           com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:558)
> > >           com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:733)
> > >           javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
> > >           org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

========================================================================
Добавленно:

```
  <servlet>
  <servlet-name>WebService</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
 <init-param>
  <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
  <param-value>tests</param-value>
  </init-param>
   <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
  </init-param>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
```

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>WebService</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/users/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

=================================================================

Мой pom.xml:

```
   <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0   http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.testing.functionality</groupId>
  <artifactId>TestingProjects</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>TestingProjects Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
   <dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>3.8.1</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
  <version>1.19</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
  <version>1.19</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
  <version>1.19</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
  <version>1.19</version>
  </dependency>
  </dependencies>
 <build>
<finalName>TestingProjects</finalName>
</build>
</project>
```

Comment: `JerseyServiceDemo.java:85`-то не стесняйтесь показать

Comment: Пожалуйста! Какие соображения ?

Comment: Воу. Без дебаггера лично мне сложно будет сказать.

Comment: В той строчке, которую вы показали, не может быть `NullPointerException`. Пересоберите проект, убедитесь что нигде ничего не закешировалось.

Comment: Roman - Как мне проверить что  негде нечего не закешировалось ?

Answer (score 2):

В web.xml должен быть конвертер в JSON

```
<servlet>
   <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
   <init-param>
       <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
       <param-value>tests</param-value>
   </init-param>
   <init-param> // это разрешает сериализовывать данные
       <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
       <param-value>true</param-value>
   </init-param>
   <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/users/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

ну и в pom.xml должна быть влючена зависимость:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
   <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
   <version>1.8</version>//ваша верия как и jersey-server
</dependency>
```

В папке tests создайте HelloController.java с таким содержимым:

```
package tests;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/test")
public class HelloController {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response createJSON() {
        return Response.ok().entity("Hello From Jersey!!!!! ").build();
    }
}
```

и перейди по [ссылке](http://localhost:8080/ProjectsTesting/users/test)

Comment: Пожалуйста. Проблема осталась.. Null Pointer! ??

Comment: обновил ответ, попробуй сделать как там написано